# Access Page item's value in console of Modal page Oracle Apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

When the popup page is of normal page template I am able to access value of page item in console without error. But when page template is changed to modal dialog the page item value is null and I am getting error. Tried

1. `apex.item("P12_item").getValue();`
2. `$v("P12_item");`

In session state I am still able to view the value.! but error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you using? Usually, when you open a modal page, you need to change the context of your console so it can read the values of the items in the modal.

In Mozilla, for example, you can find the option here:

[Context selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvPwU.png)